# Why is my 'for' loop not looping?

Tags: python, pyserial

The following python script should do following:

- wait for a key press, then
- send `X1650 Y0 Z0` to an embedded device, then
- fill the variable `line` byte by byte with the response

Altough `print (ser.in_waiting)` claims that the input buffer is properly filled, the `for` is not iterating over it.

### Code:

```
import serial
import time

# configure the serial connections
ser = serial.Serial(
    port='COM3',
    baudrate=9600,
)

while 1 :
    # Wait until user presses a key
    eingabe = input("PROMPT >> ")

    # Send text string to embedded device
    destination_position = 'X1650 Y0 Z0\r\n'
    ser.write(destination_position.encode('ascii'))

    # Wait until embedded device responds
    while ser.in_waiting == 0:
        time.sleep(0.1)

    # How long is the response?
    print ('The response is: ')
    print (ser.in_waiting)
    print (' bytes long')

    # Traverse through the queue
    line = []
    for c in ser.read():
        line.append(chr(c))
        print(line)
```

### Output:

```
D:\7-Thema\Programmieren\projects\robot\remote-control-scripts>python test.py
PROMPT >> GO!
The response is:
39
 bytes long
['X']
PROMPT >>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must specify the number of bytes to be read. But I don't know the return type so when you print a line, you will see :)  and then you can convert accordingly

```
line = ser.read(ser.in_waiting)
print("%r"%line)
```

Here is a docs [link](http://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.read)